Preview search not working - not highlight word
Macbook Preview for PDF is not working correctly. For example, if I search for some word in the pdf, it shows 30 results found, but it is not highlighting those words, and I cannot use arrows to go to any of those search results(it is greyed out)

I don’t have a direct answer (yet) but I wonder if you use Apple’s pages app to make a small document with the same several words and export it as PDF, is preview broken for all PDF or only some pdf you want to search? Also, try moving the document to the local user home folder as well as note where it’s stored (iCloud or external drive or ??) in case that matters for the indexing and search to function. Lastly, have you tailored your spotlight and checked this right after a restart of the OS?

Have you tried entering your search term in quotation marks? For example if I wanted to search the word test I would put it in quotation marks as follows "test", and it will only search for that word. Note, it will also look for words that include that letter combination (i.e. the word test can be found in the word testing), so if you want to match just the EXACT word, add a space on either side of the word but inside the quotation marks, for example " test ".
